# How to place dropdown inside mat-menu in angular material ui

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add dropdown in place of settings option in mat-menu. it will be role dropdown where user can click on Account and from menu he/she will changes his role in case of multiple role assigned to him.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

What you can do is to add a sub menu. The sub menu items are the roles.

```
<mat-menu #rootMenu="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">My Account</button>
   <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item (click)="setRole('admin')">Admin</button>
   <button mat-menu-item (click)="setRole('test')">Testuser</button>
   <button mat-menu-item (click)="setRole('admin')">Normal User</button>
</mat-menu>
```